# How to install Apache Zeppelin on existing Apache Spark standalone cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have an existing Apache Spark (1.3 version) standalone cluster on AWS and I would like to install Apache Zeppelin.

I have a very simple question, do I have to install Zeppelin on the Spark's master?

If the answer is yes, Could I use that guide https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin#build ?

thank you to everybody

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can install Zeppelin on Spark Master or any other machine which has access to the cluster. All you need to do is to specify the MASTER URL in zeppelin-env.sh or you can edit the interpreter properties on the Zeppelin Webapp.